# CSS 2 div repeat and one div in middle

Tags: html, css

I'm working with my project.
I want 3 divs to be in one line and fixed position..

- First div is repeated x
- 2nd div is in middle
- Last div is repeated x.

I want my output to be like this:
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/9o22xe2x/

```
<div class="header-fixed">
    <div class="header-bg1"></div>
    <div class="header-logo"></div>
    <div class="header-bg2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header-fixed{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.header-bg1{
background:url('images/header-bg1.png') repeat-x;
height: 88px;
left: 469px;
display: block;
}
.header-bg2{
background:url('images/header-bg2.png') repeat-x;
height: 128px;
left: 469px;
display: block;
}
.header-logo{
background:url('images/header-logo.png') no-repeat;
width: 469px;
height: 128px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an JSFiddle?

Comment: Note: You can use CSS gradient to achieve this. Also, to make `div` in one line, you must `float` them, or use `inline-block`.

Comment: You have to use float:left for all div in single row.

Comment: You may need to apply a width to each of the divs that don't contain the logo.  Additionally a float or display: inline-block would force them all on to one line.  I can't help but think this is over complicating things though, cant you have a single image for the background and then position your logo correctly?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9o22xe2x/

Comment: @RobertVerkerk jsfiddle.net/9o22xe2x

Answer (score 0):

add below to your css:

```css
.header-fixed div {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}
```

then in the HTML call it as:

```html
<div class="header-fixed">
  <div class="header-bg1"></div>
  <div class="header-logo"></div>
  <div class="header-bg2"></div>
</div>
```

try and see !

Comment: I think your answer is not displayed as wanted

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: inline-block` you can do:

1. Add that style to *child* `divs`:

   ```
   .header-fixed>div{
       display:inline-block;
       vertical-align: top;
   }
   ```
2. [Remove whitespace between those `divs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements). Note the *commented **HTML*** in the fiddle.
3. add some width to the first and third child `div` like:

   ```
   .header-bg1, .header-bg2{
       width: calc((100% - 469px)/2);
       /* 100% of parent width minus the logo width divided */
       /* with 2 will put the same width for the first and third child */
       /* and center the logo */
   }
   ```

   [caniuse CSS calc()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9o22xe2x/3/)

Note: I've added `margin: 0` to the `body` to remove it's default `margin`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation with 2 lines of HTML and a small amount of simple CSS:

- First background is a background image on the body
- Logo is an image in the header.
- Second background is on a pseudo element of the header which is positioned with `position: absolute` and `left: (logo width)` / `top: 0;`.

Tested and working Chrome, Firefox and IE 9 + (IE 8 and even IE 6 and 7 is possible with modification)

### Example

**Note:** The default margin on the body has been removed to prevent a gap.

```css
body {
  background: #D3BC00 url('http://i.imgur.com/tZR9xWD.png') repeat-x;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  background: #D3BC00;
  width: 500px;
  /* smallest size is logo width */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: #D3BC00 url('http://i.imgur.com/GkQQ4PF.png') repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 469px;
  /* logo width */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/m3EiiKN.png" />
</header>
```